# jdbc data independence without using hibernate api?

Tags: jdbc

I am trying to solve problem by using properties file but in properties file we can handle only database driver  problem.if we want to mysql to oracle database need to change all my query.the problem is now how to make query independent without hibernate api?? please suggest

Comment: Why do you need to change the query? If you use standard SQL, it should be the same for both MySQL and Oracle. The only thing you'd need to change is the connection string.

Comment: But there is some difference in query of mysql and oracle you knew it so that problem what we can do ?